# ng-switch using object keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to group an array of objects

```
var data = [ 
  {term: 'baz', description: 'Patient'}, 
  {term: 'bar', description: 'Patient'},  
  {term: 'foo', description: 'Doctor'} 
]
```

I'd now like to group this data by description for a drop down. Using underscores `_.groupBy` I end up with

```
$scope.grouped = _.groupBy(data, 'description')
{Patient: [
    {term: 'baz', description: 'Patient'},
    {term: 'bar', description: 'Patient'}
   ]
 }, 
{Doctor: [
    {term: 'foo', description: 'Doctor'}
   ]
 }
```

Can you use ng-switch with object keys?

```
<div ng-switch="grouped">
  <span ng-switch-when="Patient">
     <p>Patients</p> // only shown once to categorize the data
      // ng-repeat in here
  </span>
  <span ng-switch-when="Doctor">
     <p>Doctors</p> // only shown once to categorize the data
      // ng-repeat in here
  </span>
</div>
```

I could use `ng-switch` on the array before the grouping but then the title of the grouping gets repeated each time. What is the best way to achieve something similar to the HTML above where each title is only generated once and the data is grouped?

Desired output is

```
<h1>Patients<h1>
  <p>baz</p>
  <p>bar</p>
<h1>Doctors</h1>
  <p>foo</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to use this inside of an `ng-repeat` in which case yes you can use object keys.

```
<div ng-repeat="(group, data) in grouped">
    <div ng-switch="group">
        <div ng-switch-when="Patient">
            <h1>Patients</h1>
            <p ng-repeat="patient in data">{{patient.term}}</p>
        </div>
        <!-- same for doctor -->
    </div>
</div>
```